# DatagridColumn containing a Combobox or Textbox depending on a value of an Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate

I want to set the cell of a specific column to either a combobox or a textbox, depending on a property of the Datagrid's itemsource. How can i achieve this? Every rowitem has a property of ParameterType:

```
public enum ParameterType
    {
        Bool,
        Int,
        Double,
        String,
        DateTime,
        Severity
    }
```

If it's a Bool i want to show a Combobox with true and false, if int, double, string - a Textbox.
If a DateTime ideally an DateTimePicker and with Severity a Combobox with different Severity values.

I can't figure out how to change the DatagridColumn to achieve this....

**EDIT:**

We came up with this idea but the DataTemplateSelector specified doesn't seem to get called - i already set a breakpoint inside the first call in the SelectTemplate but it doesn't start the debug there.

DataTemplateSelector:

```
    public class InstructionsEditParameterTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SeverityTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate IntTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate BoolTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DateTimeTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var fpd = item as FunctionParameterDescription;
        if (fpd == null)
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

        switch (fpd.ParamType)
        {
            case FunctionParameterDescription.ParameterType.Severity:
                return SeverityTemplate;

            case FunctionParameterDescription.ParameterType.Bool:
                return BoolTemplate;

            case FunctionParameterDescription.ParameterType.DateTime:
                return DateTimeTemplate;

            case FunctionParameterDescription.ParameterType.Int:
                return IntTemplate;

            default:
                return DefaultTemplate;
        }
    }
```

DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplateSelector>
                        <!-- not yet called... -->
                        <Configurator:InstructionsEditParameterTemplateSelector                              
                            DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource StringItemTemplate}"
                            DateTimeTemplate="{StaticResource DateItemTemplate}"
                            BoolTemplate="{StaticResource BoolItemTemplate}"
                            SeverityTemplate="{StaticResource SeverityItemTemplate}"/>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplateSelector>
```

Resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SeverityItemTemplate">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Model.ParameterSeverityItems}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Type" SelectedValuePath="ParamType" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StringItemTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DateItemTemplate">
        <DatePicker Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BoolItemTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Ok now i feel a bit stupid... It just wasn't called because the IsReadOnly attribute of the DataGrid wasn't set to "false" ...  Well this is actually an example now how you can make it work :D

Comment: You could define a [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) with one of each of those controls in and then you could use an `EnumToVisibilityConverter` to make the correct one visible and the others hidden.

Comment: Alright cheers, i'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Extending the idea from my comment a bit, you can find out help with the `DataGridTemplateColumn` from the [`DataGridTemplateColumn` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN (Code example adapted from that page):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate" >
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding}" Visibility="{StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter, ConverterParameter=Int}" />
                <DateTimePicker SelectedDate="{Binding}" Visibility="{StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter, ConverterParameter=DateTime}" />
                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding}" Visibility="{StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter, ConverterParameter=Bool}">
                    <ComboBox.Items>
                        <ComboBoxItem>True</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>False</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBox>
                ... <!--Complete this yourself-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Some column" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I also found an `EnumToVisibilityConverter` class online for you:

[EnumToVisibilityConverter for Windows Store apps](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/enumtovisibilityconverter-for-windows-store-apps/)

Comment: I can't get it running, maybe i'm too stupid but we came up with a different solution.. edit in the post...